# ¿Como obtener los campos de la fila seleccionada y almacenarla en un array?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

tengo una tabla con unos datos, necesito obtener los valores de cada input de cada checkbox seleccionado, y almacenarlo en un array o un json para poder asi enviarlo con ajax. La cuestion es que logro recorrer los checkbox seleccionado pero no logro obtener los valores y almacenarlos alguna sugerencia? Esta es mi vista

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
     function save(){
                                
                                var elegidos = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked');
                                var cantidad = [];

                               

                                    elegidos.each(function(){

                                        cantidad.push($(this).attr('cantidad'));
                                        
                                    })

                             console.log(cantidad);


                            }
```

```html
                    <table id="detalles" class="table table-responsive">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                            <td>Guardar</td>
                                <td>Cantidad</td>
                                <td>Cantidad por Recepcionar</td>
                                <td>Cantidad OC</td>
                                <td>Codigo</td>
                                <td>Nombre</td>
                                <td>Nro OC</td>
                                <td>Sub-inv</td>
                                <td>Ubicacion</td>
                                <td>Fecha Vigencia</td>
                                <td>Nro Lote</td>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @if(!empty($po_lines_all))
                                    @foreach($po_lines_all as $key => $po)
                                    <form class="detalles">
                                                <tr id="dat-{{ $key }}">
                                                
                                                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="val[]"  id="val" class="val"  ></td>
                                                    <td><input type="number" name="cantidad[]" class="cantidad"   style="width:100%" value=""></td>
                                                    <td><input type="number" name="cantidad_recepcion[]" readonly="readonly" class="cantidad_recepcion" style="width:100%" value="{{ $po->quantity_ordered - $po->quantity_delivered }}"></td>
                                                    <td><input type="number" style="width:100%" name="cantidad_oc[]" readonly="readonly" class="cantidad_oc" value="{{ $po->quantity }}"></td>
                                                            <td>
                                                                <input type="text" style="width:100%" name="codigo[]" readonly="readonly" class="codigo" value="{{ $po->codigo }}">
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td>
                                                                <input type="text" style="width:100%" name="nombre[]" readonly="readonly" class="nombre" value="{{ $po->nombre }}">
                                                            </td>
                                                        <td style="display:none;"><input type="text" value="{{ $po->item_id }}" name="item_id[]" class="item_id" style="display:none;"></td>
                                                        
                                                        <td><input type="text" name="oc[]" class="oc" readonly="readonly" style="width:100%" value="{{ $po->segment1 }}"></td>

                                                        <td>
                                                            <select name="sub_inv[]" id="sub_inv" class="sub_inv">
                                                                <option></option>
                                                                @foreach($sub_inv as $sub)
                                                                    <option value="{{ $sub->id }}" id="subinventory_id">{{ $sub->name }}</option>
                                                                @endforeach
                                                            </select>
                                                        </td>
                                                        
                                                        <td>
                                                            <select name="locator[]" id="locator" class="locator" style="width: 100%;">
                                                                <option></option>
                                                            </select>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td><input type="date" style="width:100%" name="fecha_vigencia[]" class="fecha_vigencia"></td>
                                                        <td><input type="text"  name="nro_lote[]" class="nro_lote"  style="width:150%"></td>
                                                        <td  style="display:none;"><input type="text" style="display:none;" name="categoria_id[]" class="categoria_id" value="{{ $po->category_id}}"></td>
                                                        <td style="display:none;"><input type="text" style="display:none;" name="quantity[]" class="quantity" value="{{ $po->quantity }}"></td>
                                                        <td style="display:none;"><input type="text" style="display:none;" name="unit_meas_lookup_code[]" class="unit_meas_lookup_code" value="{{ $po->unit_meas_lookup_code }}"></td>
                                                        <td style="display:none;"><input type="text" style="display:none;" name="po_header_id[]" class="po_header_id" value="{{ $po->po_header_id }}"></td>
                                                        <td style="display:none;"><input type="text" style="display:none;" name="po_line_id[]" class="po_line_id" value="{{ $po->po_line_id }}"></td>
                                                        <td style="display:none;"><input type="text" style="display:none;" name="po_distribution_id[]" class="po_distribution_id" value="{{ $po->po_distribution_id }}"></td>
                                                        <td style="display:none;"><input type="text" style="display:none;" name="primary_uom_code[]" class="primary_uom_code" value="{{ $po->primary_uom_code }}"></td>
                                                        <!-- campos para comparar valores -->
                                                        <td style="display:none;"><input type="text" style="display:none;" name="stock_enabled_flag[]" class="stock_enabled_flag" value="{{ $po->stock_enabled_flag }}"></td>
                                                        <td style="display:none;"><input type="text" style="display:none;" name="inventory_item_status_code[]" class="inventory_item_status_code" value="{{ $po->inventory_item_status_code }}"></td>
                                                        <td style="display:none;"><input type="text" style="display:none;" name="mtl_transactions_enabled_flag[]" class="mtl_transactions_enabled_flag" value="{{ $po->mtl_transactions_enabled_flag }}"></td>
                                                    </form>
                                                 </tr>
                                        @endforeach
                                @else
                                    <tr><td colspan="10" class="alert alert-danger" style="text-align:center;">No existe registro</td></tr>
                                @endif
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Comment: Debes mostrar el código para saber como podemos ayudarte

Comment: Listo disculpa, no lo habia colocado @VictorHerasmePerez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno di con la solución al problema que presentaba o más bien la duda, el procedimiento por si alguien lo necesita, la solución es el siguiente:

```
 var toStore = {};
 var i=0;

                                $("input[type=\"checkbox\"]:checked").each(function(){
                                    toStore[i] = {};

                                    $(this).closest('td').siblings().each(function(){
                                        $(this).find(':input').each(function() {
                                            toStore[i][this.name] = this.value;
                                        });
                                    });
                                    i++;
                                });

                                details = JSON.stringify(toStore);
                                //console.log(toStore);
```